# Addition to an integer field with a form

Tags: entities

I have a bundle of image nodes of the same content type that I create in my custom form. Each image node has a field that contains a unique reference number to that node. Currently it is up to the user to add +1 to the previous image node saved and type that in the form for the next reference number. How can I add +1 to the last saved field and use the result to populate the saved field displayed on the saved node? More advanced: If I use an AJAX form that allows users to add more fields to add more pictures on the image creation form, how could I save the images with consecutive IDs?

Comment: Have you got some snippets of your code so far? If you are creating nodes with node_save, IDs will be set and returned for you...

Comment: You can use [Rules](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http://drupal.org/project/rules&ei=HcJ6UP-0OI24hAf-6oAI&usg=AFQjCNE3czi2hZQFEPxrPw2ah2DpUTc7Sg) module, you should see simple videos to learn how to do it if you does not use Rules yet.

Comment: Keep in mind file attachments already have a unique id in the file id ( fid )

Answer (score 0):

You can use the module [Prepopulate](http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) ; latest release is dev but I use it on a production site and it works like a charm.

If it doesn't work tell me, there are two other solutions : send an arg in the URL to the form (and then use Panels or the php template) and JavaScript (I can give you the code if you need it).